# Como redirecciono a vistas especificas dependiendo del usuario que acceda al sistema con jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

me podrian por favor ayudar en lo siguiente; estoy iniciando en **laravel**, he logrado crear un sistema que me solicita autenticacion para el ingreso con **jetstream** lo que requiero es que al momento de loguearse dependiendo del rol sea direccionado a las vistas destinadas para el rol correspondiente, ejemplo: administrador -> dashboard, operador -> index, usuario -> reportes..
Por ahora he intentado con tal solo dos roles.. y he intentado con este codigo..
HomeController

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user(); 
        //dd($user->roles); // Verifica los roles que tiene el usuario
        if ($user->hasRole('operator')) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.index'); 
        } elseif ($user->hasRole('operator')) {
            return redirect()->route('operator.index'); 
        } else { 
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
        
    }
```

y en el archivo de rutas web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {
      Route::get('admin', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.index');
  });
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:operator'], function () {
      Route::get('operator', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('operator.index');
  });
});
```

Anexo imagen que emite luego de loguearme tanto con operator como con admin.. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la respuesta @JulianBuxton, pero me encuentro con que sigue sin funcionar.. he modificado el codigo segun tu sugerencia.. quedando de esta forma el archivo de rutas asi:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:admin'], function () {
      Route::get('admin', [HomeController::class, 'Adminindex'])->name('admin.index');
  });
  Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:operator'], function () {
      Route::get('operator', [HomeController::class, 'Operatorindex'])->name('operator.index');
  });
});
```

// y este el codigo del controlador

```
public function Adminindex(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        
        if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.index');
        } 
    }
    public function Operatorindex(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        
        if ($user->hasRole('operator')) {
            return redirect()->route('operator.index');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buen día, y ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué error(es) te aparecen? Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega la información faltante.

Comment: Dale una mirada a este [post de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345414/laravel-8-redirect-according-to-role-after-login). No puedo comprobarlo ahora, pero haciendo una búsqueda rápida, de lo que encontré, es lo que primero intentaría

Comment: O [este de laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/customize-redirect-after-successful-password-reset-using-laravel-fortify) también parece sensato